# Checking for the return value of a function in Python

Tags: python, django, function, exception, django-rest-framework

I have a small function for database connection in Django as follows:

```
def db_connection(query_name):
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query_name)
        descr = cursor.description
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        result = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in descr], row)) for row in rows]
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        return e 
    finally:
       cursor.close()
```

This function is used in my function views for Django rest framework to execute SQL queries.The general syntax is as follows:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def foo_bar(request):
    ....
    ....
    ....
    query1 = "Select name from table"
    result = db_connection(query1)

    return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However,what I need is to change the status value in the Response tuple depending on the return value of my db_connection function i.e. to return a 200 OK if no exception occurs else a 500. How can I check if the return value of a function is an exception ?

Comment: Django has a very nice framework for accessing databases.. is there a reason you're not using it?

Comment: i am well aware of the headaches of by passing the ORM..like handling of prevention of sql injection manually to name one of them..however..this app is an analytics app and the Django ORM is just not good enough for my needs and hence the raw SQL..

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitly bypassing all the nice control flow that exceptions already give you. Don't do that.

If you just want a 500 to be returned, then don't catch the exception at all; just let it bubble up, Django's exception handling middleware will catch it and return a 500 response.

In any case, you should never catch the base Exception class; only catch the things you can actually deal with. And when you do catch an exception, you should *actually* deal with it; returning it instead of raising it is of no use whatsoever.

Comment: hmm..makes sense..so the right way to do this would be to  just use the try block without the except statement and then just finally close the connection ?

Comment: don't do the `try... finally` in your function at all, use the cursor as a context manager https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors

Answer (score 2):

I would move the try catch block in the `foo_bar` function over the `result = db_connection(query1)` code and return a 500 status from there, along with some kind of errors dict which contains a message explaining why it failed. I say this because I'm assuming you are making a REST API which must always return an answer and not crash the normal django way.

Comment: however that would defeat my purpose of making the db_connection function in the first place..i have multiple views and would prefer having a one line function call rather than the whole try catch block..

Comment: You could try using `isinstance(result, Exception)`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: What I'm not sure is how the behavior is if you just don't treat the exception and let it bubble up.

Comment: yes..i completely get what you are saying..it is a rest API and i would want to exactly know the response being given back rather than the framework throwing up an error